# Heroku deployment with sibling git repos

Tags: java, git, maven, heroku, server

We have a maven project structured so that in the main src folder we have two sibling git repositories, one that holds the server code and one that holds common code. From what I've seen of heroku, it looks like a deployed app is restricted to a single git repo that holds the entire project. Is there a way around this? If so, where can I look to find this information?

Comment: Unfinished title. Oops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the "siblings" are Git submodules, you can use Heroku's support for Git submodules:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-submodules

Otherwise, you could opt to deploy precompiled artifacts (JAR files):
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-executable-jar-files